# Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence such that $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq r<1$ and $S_N = a_1 + \cdots + a_N$. Prove $|S - S_N| < \frac{r^N+1}{1-r}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I've solved the question in the title and I'd appreciate some feedback.

$$ \sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq r \Rightarrow a_n \leq r^n \Rightarrow \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} \leq \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}{r^n}$$

Let $S = \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ and since $a_n$ is a positive sequence 
$$|S-S_N| = S - S_N=\Sigma_{n=N+1}^{\infty}a_n \leq \Sigma_{n=N+1}^{\infty}{r^n}$$ 
Let $a = r^{N+1} + r^{N+2} + \cdots$ then $r \cdot a = r^{N+2} + r^{N+3} \cdots$ which gives us
$$ a - r \cdot a = r^{N+1} + (r^{N+2} - r^{N+2}) + \cdots = r^N+1 $$
$$ \Rightarrow a = \frac{r^{N+1}}{1-r} $$
And we got
$$ |S-S_N| \leq \frac{r^{N+1}}{1-r}  $$

As you can see I've proved $\leq$ instead of $<$ but I'm not sure where or if I made a mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct. You cannot prove strict inequality. If $a_n=r^{n}$ for all $n$ then $|S-S_N|=\frac {r^{N+1} } {1-r}$.